# Sun's photosphere slowing down

Tags: photons, sun

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbpiovW507M I heard that the sun's photosphere is slowing down because photons from the sun's core hit it. But wouldn't the other layers of the sun slow down too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very new work by [Cunnyngham et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00873). They suggest that the transfer of angular momentum by photons exiting the Sun - something akin to [Poynting-Robertson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%E2%80%93Robertson_effect) drag - is able to account for the sharp radial gradient in angular velocity that is inferred in the Sun's photosphere by helioseismology measurements.

This effect will only be large in the photosphere of the Sun, where the mean free path of the visible photons (that dominate the flux) becomes large enough for them to escape the Sun entirely. In deeper layers photons are emitted and then reabsorbed almost immediately which reduces any torque and, because the density of the Sun increases steeply with depth, the moment of inertia of a shell of material is much larger just below the photosphere and thus a smaller shear would be produced for the same torque.